# how can open my app in device while click on news-feed on facebook in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I want to open my app while click on post shared by my app on facebook in iOS  device.

If there is any example please provide me.

Answer (score 2):

First create deeplink url from this link
 "[https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1555401071407647/?platform=app-links-host](http://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1555401071407647/?platform=app-links-host%22)".
 And it will return url like @"https://fb.me/16753168070237260".
 add this to your FBGraphObject like this

```
NSMutableDictionary <FBOpenGraphObject> *object =  [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"myApp:event"                                                    title:@"testing title"                                                    image:nil                                                      url:@"https://fb.me/16753168070237260"                                              description:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your project `plist`

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.test.DEMO</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>DEMO</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Whenever you open URL **"DEMO://"** in phone's browser, it will open your application if it already install (use your app bundle name instead of "DEMO")

So either you can send "DEMO://" with your facebook post, so when you click on "DEMO://" it will open link in browser that will open your app or save this to a server file and open that file using following code

save following code in php file and store that file to server and send file URL (that will open this php file from your server) with your facebook post or news-feed so when you will click on given link it will

```
  <?php
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function() { \n
         window.location = \"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/DEMO...\";\n
         }, 25);\n
         window.location = \"DEMO://?l=1\";\n
    </script>";

  ?>
```

Now when your app open from browser, if you want some operation to perform the you need to add following method in your delegate class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    //add your code
}
```

Comment: still not working. Do you have any objective c code?

Comment: @AkleshRathaur, Open your plist file As source code and add first block of code and then in your phone's safari type **AppBundleName://**, that will open your app

Comment: I want to open my app from facebook post shared by my app.

Comment: yes, then pass that link(AppBundleName://) with your facebook post

Comment: how are you trying, just share your code otherwise it is really difficult to help you

Comment: <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
        <dict>
        <key>URLName</key>
        <string>myApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
        <string>myApp</string>
        <string>fb89789789779</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
        </array>

Comment: @AkleshRathaur, It would be great, if you share what have you done?